# Changing HTML form layout based on select option selected using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is it possible to set a variable in thymeleaf and then change it depending on an option in a select element and then display a specific div based on the selection? Here's what I mean.

I have three options in select:

```
1) DESKTOP_PC
2) LAPTOP_PC
3) TABLET_PC
```

When the user selects `DESKTOP_PC`, I would like to show the div with the related inputs for it. Likewise if it's `LAPTOP_PC` or `TABLET_PC`.

Only problem is, I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.

The other thing, is that I have the following:

In my entry class I have an enum class:

```
public static enum Type {
    DESKTOP_PC,
    LAPTOP_PC,
    TABLET_PC
}
```

In my Thymeleaf form, I have the following to access and display this enum:

```
<div class="section-question">
    <p>Type</p>
    <select name="type" th:field="$*{type}">
        <option th:each="type : ${T(com.project.entities.Entry.Type).values()}" th:value="${type}" th:text="${type}" ></option>
    </select>
</div>

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To achieve what you want we need to to take help of Javascript or jQuery.

1. Write an onchange function on select tag.
2. Get the value of option selected inside the function.
3. Show/hide div depending on value

Vote if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

it is very possible, but has very little to do with Java or Thymeleaf, even though you could do it with them too (not recommended)

All you need to do is create basic JavaScript function that onClick to different options makes different divs visible (through adding/removing classes with css defined in them like `display: none;`).

Of course you could implement it on backend, through each click being a separate request sent to a controller that then saves the option into a for example boolean variable and based on this variable returns a different thymeleaf view but that is an awkward looking solution for such simple case that doesn't really require backend processing.

Any simple book on JS will show you how to do this, I can recommend `A smarter way to learn JS` for this scenario